# How To Generate Random Questions And Send Through Webservices?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I want to generate a set of random questions and store in an array.  Then I want to transfer the data through web services by converting the array into JSON...  I'm not sure where to begin.  Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to be more precise with your question. What have you tired? What is the database structure? etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The very first thing you need to do is to read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how and what to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peddy, You can go with following steps :

1. Get a database ready at first with a large set of Questions in a
   table in your database.
2. Create a stored procedure to get a set of
       random questions from that table.
3. Now you can go with **Asp.Net** to
       create a web service.
4. Use **json.Net methods** to convert your data
       fetched from DB in json format.
5. Send this jSon object using your web
       service.

I think stratagy will work :)